# ANTLR ambiguity

Tags: parsing, antlr, ambiguous-grammar

I need to match in `ANTLR` a message containing 2 fields separated by a /
First field can have `1..3` digits, the second field can have `1..2` digits,

this does not work

```
msg: f1 '/' f2;

f1: DIGIT(DIGIT(DIGIT)?)? ;
f2: DIGIT(DIGIT)?
```

1. How can I avoid ambiguity in such a case?
2. Is there a more elegant way to express the number of repetitions with `ANTLR`?

Thanks a lot
   Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIR (it's some time ago I last used ANTLR), you can use "fragment" to avoid having f1 and f2 as a top level token:

```
msg: f1 '/' f2;

fragment f1: DIGIT(DIGIT(DIGIT)?)? ;
fragment f2: DIGIT(DIGIT)?
```

This allows you to have an ambiguity between f1 and f2, because they don't have to match on their own.

Comment: I still get the same error :-( [MismatchedTokenException]
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my fault: I solved it; if DIGIT was a fragment too, it was not working; if DIGIT is NOT a fragment, it works!!
Thanks